# groupby regex across rows and aggregate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Is it possible to apply a function which operates on concatenated rows in pandas, and aggregates the dataframe based on the output?

Example:

I want to apply a regex along the joined column of this dataframe:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['a', 0],['b',0],['c',0], [' ', 0], ['1', 1], ['2', 1], ['3',1], [' ', 0], ['r',0], ['.', 0], [' ', 0], ['a',0]])
```

## output:

```
    0  1
0   a  0
1   b  0
2   c  0
3      0
4   1  1
5   2  1
6   3  1
7      0
8   r  0
9   .  0
10     0
11  a  0
```

Now I would like to combine column 0 using a `re.split()` on the joined text data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(re.split(r'([\s\.])',''.join(a[0])))
```

which gives this:

```
     0
0  abc
1     
2  123
3     
4    r
5    .
6     
7     
8    a
```

However, it loses the other columns.

How can I maintain the DataFrame while performing this operation?

The other columns here may be taken as the mean or just the most common element from the concatenated strings. In order to provide the final output:

```
     0  1
0  abc  0
1       0
2  123  1
3       0
4    r  0
5    .  0
6       0
7       0
8    a  0
```

Are there good pandas functions for this type of grouping?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works. The only glitch is that you are assigning the output of regex to a instead of a[0]

```
a[0] = pd.DataFrame(re.split(r'([\s\.])',''.join(a[0])))
a.dropna()
```

Will give you

```
    0   1
0   abc 0
1       0
2   123 0
3       0
4   r   1
5   .   1
6       1
7       0
8   a   0
```

Comment: This loses the assignments in the second column. I think there is a group function that is required in order to maintain `123` as `1` in the second column.